# How to select all elements that have a partial string match with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these elements:

```
<div>foo</div>
<div>foo_bar</div>
<div>bar</div>
```

I would like to select the first two elements, targeting them by the fact they both have the string 'foo' as text.

I have tried to use `:contains` but I can't seem to implement it correctly.

Comment: `but I can't seem to implement it correctly` - perhaps you could show how you tried :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:contains(foo)` works just fine:

```js
const foos = $('div:contains(foo)');
console.log(foos.length);
console.log(foos[0].outerHTML);
console.log(foos[1].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>foo</div>
<div>foo_bar</div>
<div>bar</div>
```